# Why browser.get method does not go to specified url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, protractor

I have a folder structure like this:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1hTj.jpg)

And I am following [this tutorial](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-with-protractor-and-cucumber)

My package.json file is like this:

```
{
  "name": "node_cucumber_e2e",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "Sample E2E by Bill to learn cucumber and protractor",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "start-driver": "node .\\node_modules\\protractor\\bin\\webdriver-manager start",
    "update-driver": "node .\\node_modules\\protractor\\bin\\webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "node .\\node_modules\\protractor\\bin\\protractor configs/protractor.conf.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Sample_project",
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "protractor": "^5.4.2"
  }
}
```

I do following things:

1. install **protractor** locally
2. update **webdriver-manager** via `npm run update-driver`
3. start **webdriver-manager** via `npm run start-driver`
4. edit the protractor.conf like following

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: [`../tests/e2e/specs/*.js`],
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080/',  
    framework: 'jasmine',
  }
```

Then when I tried to start protractor via `npm run protractor`, the browser is open, however, it does not go to the url I specify and the console is this ==> [output console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEKto.jpg)

My spec js file is, hope someone could help me out

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
    it ('should have a title', function() {
        browser.get('https://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Super Calculator');
    });
});
```

Comment: The tutorial you provided calls `then` on the return value of `browser.get`, this means that `browser.get` returns a `Promise`. You should also call `then` or switch to `async/await`. I looked at [the documentation](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.get) for `browser.get` and it is misleading, it looks like the method is synchronous when it is not, looking at [the actual code](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5.4.1/lib/browser.ts#L859) for `browser.get` it is definitely returning a `Promise`.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger In protractor versions below 6 (which OP is using) promises are handled behind the scenes using webdriverJS' promise manager unless explicitly disabled with the `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER:false` setting in the config. This allows asynchronous actions to be written in the above manner. I'm not sure why that tutorial is written like that as that shouldn't be required. OP, can you try adding a `browser.driver.sleep(5000)` after your `.get` and verify the same behaviour

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things to be taken care of here:

1. The way you call the selenium driver to run the tests. There are other ways of doing it too. I prefer to do the `directConnect = true` and go for `headless` option to be able to debug better where you are facing an issue. Refer the below code snippet for `protractor-conf.js` file:

   ```js
   export const config: Config = {
     directConnect: true,
      capabilities: {
          'browserName': 'chrome',
           chromeOptions: {
                //args: [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu" ]
          },
      },
   }
   ```
2. Since `browser.get() & browser.getTitle()` is an asynchronous call that we are making, you can handle it promise returned using either the `then()` or the `await` for every `async` call that is done.

   I prefer using `async/await` to handle such calls and I would rewrite `spec` as:

   ```js
      describe('Protractor Demo App',() => {
        it ('should have a title', async() => {
           await browser.get('https://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
           expect(await browser.getTitle()).toEqual('SuperCalculator');
       });
      });
   ```

   IMO it helps to handle the promises more effectively while keeping my code clean.
   Lemme know if this works out for you!

**Further improvements**:

To update webdriver-manager use in your `package.json`,

```
 "webdriver-update": "./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update"
```

instead of `npm run update-driver`.